# Random variable’s distribution depends on another random variable: eg $Y\sim N(0,1/X^2)$

Tags: probability

Is it possible for the distribution of $Y$ to depend on another RV $X,$ eg,

$$Y\sim N(0,1/X^2)?$$

And then we can choose to specify their joint distribution, eg,  $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=N(0,1)N(0,1/X^2)$?

It seems that any two random variables that have a joint distribution that doesn’t factor might depend on each other like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're describing is basically the fact that a joint density $f_{XY}(x,y)$ can always be factored as $f_{Y|X}(y\mid x)f_X(x)$, i.e. the product of a conditional and a marginal distribution. If they're also independent then $f_{Y|X} = f_Y$ so we'd have $f_{XY}=f_Y\cdot f_X$, but that's not true in general.

In your example you have $Y\mid X \sim \mathcal N(0, X^{-2})$ and $X\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$ so this does completely determine $f_{XY}$ via $f_{XY}(x,y) = f_{Y|X}(y\mid x)f_X(x)$.

Comment: @user0 for that I would use the fact that $f_Y(y) = \int f_{XY}(x,y)\,\text dx$ so it's still completely determined, although in general it may not have a tidy analytical form

Comment: So no good way to get it from $Y|X$.

Comment: @user0 you can think of it as integrating $f_{Y|X}$ with respect to $f_X\,\text dx$, but it's necessary to also have $f_X$, $f_{Y|X}$ by itself doesn't determine $f_Y$.

Comment: Yep got it, thanks